# Applying loadMask() to a single element in extjs?

Tags: load, extjs4, extjs, mask

How to apply loadMask to only one element, and not the whole browser width-height?
default
[image]

here, only one element is masked, and a messageBox is in center, inside this element and not the whole display...
[image]

any ideas?

EDIT:

@Molecule , thanks, but this is when data is loading from some source, what i need is :

```
{
    xtype:"button",
    text:"Alert",
    handler: function(){

        Ext.Msg.show({
        title:'Save Changes?',
        msg: 'You are closing ?',
        buttons: Ext.Msg.YES,
        setLoading: // here somehow only mask parent element, and position alertBox...
    }

}
```

Comment: You speak about elements but they are components.

Comment: @Chris, yes they are [Components](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component) :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Every component has it's own `loadMask` property. You can use it by calling `YourComponent.setLoading`. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/5eEEq/1/) to illustrate what I'm talking about.

Another way is using `new Ext.LoadMask(YourComponent.el, {msg:"Please wait..."});`. You can look at usage in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/pKq8X/).

**UPDATE**

Here is code example which shows how to apply ExtJS4 loadMask and MessageBox to specified Widget

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Border Layout',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        title: 'West Region is collapsible',
        region:'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        width: 400,
        id: 'west-region-container',
        layout: 'fit'
    },{
        title: 'Center Region',
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: 'fit',
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getCmp('west-region-container').el, {useMsg: false});
myMask.show();
var msg = Ext.Msg.show({
    title:'Save Changes?',
    msg: 'Bla-Bla',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
    modal: false
});
msg.alignTo(Ext.getCmp('west-region-container').el, 'c-c');
```

And here is [try-it-yourself example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/pKq8X/2/).

Comment: And all components in ExtJS has at least an `el` property which is in fact an `Ext.Element` which is pointing to the wrapping div. As long as you can access this `el` element, you can always call up `.mask()` or `.unmask()` on this el, or any method defined in `Ext.Element`.

Comment: can one provide with simple example of Ext.Msg.show and loadNask??Please

Comment: @Ingol, of course. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/pKq8X/2/)

Comment: @Ingol, I've provided example of Ext.Msg.show and loadMask. And added it into my post

Comment: Fiddle is broken, now.