# how to remove loading mask from extjs v 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs

i am using Extjs 4.1 when store load its mask the grid. store load every 10 sec how to remove loading mask from grid 
try with this option

```
loadMask:false
viewConfig : {
    loadMask:false
}
```

but not able to remove mask effect is there any way to remove mask effect from grid in extjs 4.1

Comment: when can I get my hands on 4.1? :)

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-developer-preview/ download performance preview

Answer (score 1):

Try with, [.unmask()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-unmask). Every element in extjs has at least an *el* property which is in fact an Ext.Element. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6776238/765628) question. Also, you could provide some code so it would be easier! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at an example.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7l4)
Also If this does not work you should check :

- your event handlers
- Or some other component rendered over your grid (unlikely...)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your store as:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    root : 'data',
    autoLoad : true,
    Ext.LoadMask({
        disabled : true
    }),
    proxy : ......,
    fields : [.....]
})
```

Test once